# Web Essential for Visual Studio Sass compile wrong

Tags: css, web, visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Web Essentials.
I am coding a web site with Sass (scss) and I have problem with compile it. I have read many articles that Web Essentials doesn´t support it, but I found it works even in options.

But there is a problem, for example:

```
$primaryColor: #eeccff;

body {
  $primaryColor: #ccc;
  background: $primaryColor;
}

p {
  color: $primaryColor;
}
```

Paragraph (p) have color: #ccc, that is not correct.

Any advice?

Thanks.

EDIT:
How can I upgrade the Sass compiler for Web Essentials?

Comment: This behavior is consistent with Sass 3.2.  In Sass 3.3, changing variables in this way would raise a deprecation warning.  Variables having scope like you're expecting didn't come about until 3.4.  I don't know anything about Web Essentials, so I don't know how one would go about upgrading the version of Sass it compiles with.

Comment: Please note that tool requests (eg. Is there something better?) are considered off-topic and this question will likely be closed as a result.  If you were to rephrase it to "how can I upgrade the Sass compiler for Web Essentials", you would be able to stay on-topic and keep the question open.