# getting different results when compiling Sass with LiveReload for OSX

Tags: css, macos, sass, livereload

I'm not sure whats happening. I'm new to Sass, so I was following this begginers guide: https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-sass

For practicing (and hoping to use it as my developing tool) I set LiveReload to compile .scss files. But when testing the variable scope I got unexpected results.

In style.scss I have the following code:

```
$primaryColor: #eeccff;

body {
  $primaryColor: #ccc;
  background: $primaryColor;
}

p {
  color: $primaryColor;
}

// When compiled, our paragraph selector's color is #eeccff
```

So p is supposed to get color: #eeccff. But this is what I'm getting:

```
body {
  background: #cccccc; }

p {
  color: #cccccc; }
```

I tested the same code in [sassmeister.com](http://sassmeister.com) and it worked as expected, just like the tutorial says:

```
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

p {
  color: #eeccff;
}
```

Again, I'm using LiveReload for Mac. And these are the compiling options:
[image]

Does anyone has an idea of why is this happening?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I found this question where someone was experiencing a very similar problem in a different situation: [Web Essential for Visual Studio Sass compile wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095519/web-essential-for-visual-studio-sass-compile-wrong)

Apparently it has to do with the Sass version you use. But how do I change that for LiveReload? How you change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just changed from Sass compiler. I had to stop using LiveReload and compile with Koala to have the expected results. Couldn't manage to change LiveReload Sass gem.